# Android onQueryTextChange: how do I eliminate repetitive matching error for SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I set up an OnQueryTextListener on a SearchView that returns results from a RecyclerView list.  The SearchView expands on the Toolbar when the user clicks a Search icon.  All is working fine except for one issue.  When a character (for example, the letter "z") is entered by the user in the SearchView and the letter is not found in the in the list, a Toast occurs and the query is cleared for the next input by the user.

The problem arises when "z" is entered a second time by the user.  In this case, since the content "z" from the second entry exactly matches the previous content "z" from the first entry, the OnQueryTextChange() does not recognize any "Change" in the content by comparing the second entry to the first and therefore the "Not Found" Toast does not run and the query is not cleared.  Is this supposed to occur?  How would I handle this so that the second "z" that is entered will run the "Not Found" Toast and clear the query (since we know that "z" is not in the list)?

```
MainActivity.java
...
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList = adapter.filter(adapter.listItems, newText);

        if(filteredModelList.size() > 0) {
            adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);                    
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSearchView.setQuery("", false);  // Clear the query
            return false;
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
});

Adapter file:

public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
private Context mContext;    

public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItems) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.mContext = context;
}
...
public void setFilter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    listItems.addAll(listItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> filter(ArrayList<ListItem> models, String query) {

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListItem model : models) {
            final String text = model.getTodo().toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(query)) {
                    filteredModelList.add(model);
                }
        }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

Comment: `RecyclerView.Adapter` has no `filter` /  `setFilter` methods, so nobody knows what you are actually doing there

Comment: Ok, that means we have to create our own filters, hence some problems like this one with onQueryTextChange?

Comment: no, it means that you can use some generic adapter like [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) for example

Comment: Looks very good, I will have to study. By the way are the "synchronize" and "locks" code used to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: @pskink Above I added the setFilter and filter methods in the Adapter.

Comment: so use: `class Adapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<ListItem, Adapter.VH> { ...` and filter your data in android way: `adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint)`

Comment: @pskink Ok.  Does it only work on API 21 and >?

Comment: tried 19 but should work on 21+ too..., of course you need to override `matches` method to indicate what items match your filtering constraint

Comment: Ok, mine is >=14 so do you think I can still use Matchable...?

Comment: yes, if you want easy custom filtering

Comment: Ok very good I will try.  I appreciate your comments, advice and sharing of your Adapter.  Cheers.

Comment: good luck then...